# Select option not passing values

Tags: php, html

My select option is not passing values. I don't know why this isn't working any help would be appreciated but i have no idea what is going on.

HTML/PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ $Name = isset($_POST['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) :''; echo "
<a href='index.php'>
  <-- Your Home Page</a>
    </br>
    </br>"; echo "
    <table border='1'>
      <form action='' method='post'>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Car</th>
          <th>Night</th>
          <th>Siteid</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>LHA</th>
          <th>AAS</th>
          <th>LS</th>
          <th>Update</th>
        </tr>"; $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE Name = '$Name' ORDER BY Date"; $sth = $pdo->query($sql); while($row = $sth->fetch()) { $Car = $row['Car']; echo "
        <form action='' method='post'>"; echo "
          <tr>"; echo "
            <td>" . $row['Name']. "</td>"; echo "
            <td>
              <input type='text' name='Car' placeholder='".$row[' Car ']."' value=''>
            </td>"; echo "
            <td>
              <input type='text' name='Car' placeholder='".$row[' Night ']."' value=''>
            </td>"; echo "
            <td>
              <input type='text' name='Car' placeholder='".$row[' Siteid ']."' value=''>
            </td>"; echo "
            <td>
              <input type='text' name='Car' placeholder='".$row[' Date ']."' value=''>
            </td>"; echo "
            <td>
              <input type='text' name='Car' placeholder='".$row[' LHA ']."' value=''>
            </td>"; echo "
            <td>
              <input type='text' name='Car' placeholder='".$row[' AAS ']."' value=''>
            </td>"; echo "
            <td>
              <input type='text' name='Car' placeholder='".$row[' LS ']."' value=''>
            </td>"; echo "
            <input type='hidden' name='PID' value='".$row[' PID ']."' />"; echo "
            <td>
              <input type='submit' name='submit' value='".$row[' PID ']."' />
            </td>"; echo "</tr>"; echo "</form>"; } echo "</table>"; $pdo = NuLL; }Else{ Echo "Pick a user"; } ?>
```

HTML Form

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <select name="name" id="name">
        <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?=$row['user_id']?>">
          <?=$row[ "user_name"]?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: `<option value="">` is why the value is not being passed. You're setting it as `""`.

Comment: Your select option doesn't have value `<option value="">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have no value in your option tag

try this

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="name" id="name">
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?php=$row["user_name"]?>"> <?php echo $row["user_name"]?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and use php tag like this its better , instead what you are using at the moment

```
$Name = isset($_POST['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) :'';
<?php echo $row["user_name"]?>// i dont know why you have this line here
```

and to display the result

```
<?php echo $Name;?>
```

Comment: As i said in my question i did this and it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Also When i use your code my drop down just shows " "> "

Comment: Still not working hmm, going to post my "complete" code, so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way please:

```
<option value="<?=$row["user_name"]?>"> <?=$row["user_name"]?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value to post. Like this:

```
<option value="<?=$row["user_name"]?>"> <?=$row["user_name"]?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the value inside the `<option>` tags, you have to remove the property  `value=""`. Your line become:

```
<option><?=$row["user_name"]?></option>
```

the property `value="something"` is useful when you want to display some "human readable" information but send something more usable for your system.

Typically, you can display user_name (what you put inside the tags), and send user_id like this:

```
<option value="<?=$row['user_id']?>"><?=$row["user_name"]?></option>
```